# How can I switch from an MBA to a Masters program in a different subject?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, computer-science, transfer-student

I am an international student currently enrolled in a MBA program. This is my first semester here and I want to transfer to a different program in a different college. I have a 3-year BSC (Honors) in computing but my grades weren't great. I want to transfer to a MS in Computer Science. However, it seems that most programs require me to have taken certain classes like data structures and statistics, which were not offered in my bachelors program. My plan is to transfer from my MBA program to a bachelors program, take those classes, and then take the GRE and apply for MS. Is that possible? What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

Contact the school and department you're interested in, send them your transcript, and ask which and how many of the credits you've already taken would be accepted if you applied as a transfer student.  Don't expect to keep too many of them.